# Oracle : How to replace a table by another table

Tags: oracle

I am having two tables with exact same schema(`table_from` and `table_to`).Now I need to copy the data of `table_from` to table `table_to` in a way that only values of `table_from` will be there in both tables.

**table_to:**

```
id    name    desc
-----------------------
1     a       abc
2     b       def
3     c       adf
```

**table_from:**

```
id    name    desc
-----------------------
1     x       123
2     y       345
```

**Now after replacement, the 'table_to' should be.**

```
id    name    desc
-----------------------
1     x       123
2     y       345
```

Comment: With exact same **schema**? What does that mean? Do you mean with the same *structure*? In particular: is the data type of column `desc` the same in both tables? What you show seems to suggest otherwise.

Comment: @mathguy, Yes I mean same structure (same column and data types etc).

Comment: Important question: does this have to be part of a transaction (e.g. is this being run regularly in your code), or is it a one-off maintenance task you need to do? In other words, if the process fails, do you want to be able to rollback to the starting position? If users are in the system at the time, do you care if their processes fail while you're halfway through running this?

Comment: @JeffreyKemp, It was just a maintains task, actually I have created a mojo script which will update the database. But this script I need to run on different databases.For that what I am doing, just creating some temporary tables by a script and then replacing them manually(So that while the script is running there will be no impact for users).

Comment: If you don't want any impact for users, you will want to use the transactional approach (delete + insert).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to delete everything from `table_to` and then to copy over the data from `table_from`.

```
truncate table table_to;

insert into table_to
  select * from table_from;
```

Two notes:

You could drop `table_to` and recreate it with `create table table_to as select * from table_from`. That is a bad idea; if you have triggers on `table_to`, or procedures depending on the table, they will be affected.

You could `delete from table_to` instead of `truncate`; however, that will create redo and undo, and possibly take a long time. If you do not need to undo your changes or recover from crashes, `truncate` will work, and it will be quite a bit faster.

Comment: Actually If I am going to `drop` first then `create` using `create table table_to as select * from table_from' it was giving error to me ("Error starting at line : 1 in command - create table table_to as (select * from table_from) Error report - SQL Command: table TABLE_TO Failed: Warning: execution completed with warning").